# GCC - export class method as function from .so

Tags: c++, gcc

i have a .so library with a class with many methods:

```
TestClass {
    public: void method1(int x) {
        cout << "test" << endl;
    }
}
```

I'd like to have an ability to import `method1` method as if it is a function with `this` passed as first argument:

```
method1(TestClass* self, int x)
```

Of course I can write tons of glue methods like this:

```
method1(TestClass* self, int x) {
    self->method1(x);
}
```

I can also write some macros to reduce the amount of that code, but maybe there is a better way to export class methods as functions in GCC? AFAIK, MSVS supports exporting methods with `__declspec(dllexport)`, not sure what signatures do attributed methods get though.

Comment: One of the most reliable ways I've seen in C or C++ libraries is just that: passing opaque handlers and using library functions later on by passing the handle around. Could you explain why that wouldn't suit you?

Comment: @MarcoA. because I already have these classes and cannot modify them since they are used across the app.

Comment: "I can write tons of glue methods like this" - you'll need to write ton of C declarations anyway. Dummy implementations can be generated from those via simple script.